# How to drop rows which has elements equal to a specific value

Tags: pandas

I have a file which looks like

```
1618246950  0.000   0.000   0.003   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  9   0
1618387251  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.021   0.012   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0
1618436689  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  9   0
1618494414  0.005   0.002   0.001   0.000   0.002   0.005   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  1   0
1618499491  0.000   0.000   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0
```

I want to drop the rows which contains elements equal to minus one.

The following code could drop the rows if columns 1 equal to -1, but each columns could have -1.

```
df=df[df[1] != -1.0 ]
```

or

```
for i in range(1,15)
   df=df[df[i] != -1.0 ]
```

15 is the index of the last column.

so is there a pandas-style way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
df=df[-df.applymap(lambda x: x==-1).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, all of your sample data contains rows with elements equal to minus one, so you should get back an empty DataFrame.

However, this is how I believe you should go about this goal:

```
df_new = df[df.apply(lambda x: x != -1, axis=1).all(axis=1)]
```